# Replace commas for enum into pipes

Tags: php, replace

whats is the best way to replace all commas for XX(a,s,d,f) into pipes in a long string like

```
`exp` x(10) XX('s','44','f','dd','sddd') some other text here, text here , other text here
```

i want to replace commas only in this `XX('s','44','f','dd','sddd')` part [commas only in the brackets]

Comment: Have you actively tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i fixed it but still open for other solutions

```
while (preg_match('/\(([^\)]*)\)/', $tableCols)){
                $tableCols = preg_replace('/\(([^\)]*)\)/e','"[[[".str_replace(\',\',\'|\',\'$1\')."]]]"', $tableCols);
            }
            $tableCols = str_replace('[[[', '(', $tableCols);
            $tableCols = str_replace(']]]', ')', $tableCols);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like:

```
while (preg_match('/\((.*),(.*)\)/', $foo))
    $foo = preg_replace('/\((.*),(.*)\)/', '($1|$2)', $foo);
```

Comment: this is the current implementation :p it replaces all commas , need to replace only those inside the brackets

Comment: that's strange… for me, it worked well: http://rapidwolf.p.ht/img/11.07.2013-13%3A24%3A18.png

Comment: actually didn't work either . i guess the problem is there are brackets with one value only (no commas) , i fixed the example

Answer (score 1):

A simple string parser would probably be quicker than a regex. [**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/3sTLWVPe).

```
<?php
    $string = "`exp` x(10) XX('s','44','f','dd','sddd') some other text here, text here , other text here";

    $inParentheses = false;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
        if ($inParentheses) {
            if ($string[$i] == ")") {
                $inParentheses = false;
            } else if ($string[$i] == ",") {
                $string[$i] = "|"; //The replacement character
            }
        } else if ($string[$i] == "(") {
            $inParentheses = true;
        }
    }

    var_dump($string);
?>
```

Comment: `XX('s'|'44','f','dd','sddd')` other commas not replace ;)

Comment: @RonanDejhero Check out my edit - a simple string parsing would do the trick (probably faster - albeit filling some more lines).